# About slicing of lists in Python

Tags: python, list

I am trying to make two copies of a list, using slicing, called `testlist`. The two copies are `test1`,`test2`. Now I am editing `test2` and the values of `test1` change. I am not sure why this is happening? I know that slicing creates a new copy of `testlist`(with a different reference) but somehow `test1` and `test2` are still related. Any ideas why? Here is the code:

```
testlist=[[[1,1,1],[1,1,1],[1,1,1]]]
vertices=[]
m=3
for i in range(m):
    for j in range(m):
        vertices.append([i,j])
randv=random.choice(vertices)[:]
test1=testlist[-1][:]
print('test1: ')
print(test1)
test2=testlist[-1][:]
M=[[4,4,4],[4,4,4],[4,4,4]]
uniformv=random.uniform(0,1)
prob=np.exp(beta*M[randv[0]][randv[1]])/(np.exp(beta*M[randv[0]][randv[1]])+np.exp(-beta*M[randv[0]][randv[1]]))
if uniformv<prob:
    test2[randv[0]][randv[1]]=+1
else:
    test2[randv[0]][randv[1]]=-1
print('test1: ')
print(test1)
```

The print statement for `test1` before and after editing `test2` yields:

```
test1: 
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1]]
test1: 
[[1, 1, 1], [1, 1, -1], [1, 1, 1]]
```

Please run the code a few times to see different values for `test1` because of the usage of random variables.

Comment: `[:]` only makes a *shallow copy* of a list - the objects contained in the list are also contained in the copy, and modifications to them will be visible via both the original and the copy.  `copy.deepcopy()` would be one solution.

Comment: `test1=testlist[-1][:]` and `test2=testlist[-1][:]` each make a separate list object, each of which contains three separate `[1, 1, 1]` lists (which are distinct within `testlist`) - but they each contain **the same sequence of** `[1, 1, 1]` lists.